# Why does bootstrap 3 set a blue rectangle border in my buttons and other html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxguj.png

What is that blue rectangle line? I want it to be on my control whenever I want to use it. So if I want to remove it, I should be able to for the element. I use bootstrap 3.

Comment: Check this out: http://goo.gl/zUXOCx

Please share your code, so we can help further.

Comment: where is your code...??

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you have and what you've tried?

Comment: i believe that this is the default `:active` or `:focus` pseudo css selector for `buttons` , `textareas`  ,`inputs` etc. Trying doing `.urEleName:focus { border: 0px; }`

Comment: @RahulChaudhari This is simple, we don't need any code to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below `CSS` anywhere in the `stylesheet` or internally:

```
button:focus {
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: add `!important` to the `CSS` like `outline:0 !important` or `outline:none !important`

Answer (score 0):

The blue rectangle line you're pointing out is a line drawn around elements to let them stand out, a so called outline. Imagine a user with only a keyboard navigating through a website, the outline is a good reference to show the user which element is active/has focus. When the outline is on a menu item for example, it shows the user that hitting enter will propably bring him to that particular page.

There is an outline style by default in most browsers, Bootstrap styled it their own way.

More on the outline styling property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

To get rid of the outline for buttons in Bootstrap you could use:

```
.btn:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12056/

-edit

As Guruprasad Rao pointed out, the valid outline property is **none**,  according to W3C schools.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle I added, put focus on the input field and use TAB to see the difference between the buttons.